# Grails app with controller does not work with + (plus sign) in the query param

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails app. I have defined a controller which accepts query param. The value that is being pass has a `+` sign in the value, example : `foo+ bar`. When I tried to the read this value I only get `foo  bar`. UI is encoding the `+` to `%2B`.

Complete url : `/resourcename?queryName=foo%2B%20bar`

grails version : 2.5.3
java version : 8

This is a legacy application, I am having trouble running this locally.

What class can i check to how the querying string is decoded ?
What other versions of package can i provide ?

I have tried a sample app with 2.5.3, the sample project seems to work fine. The legacy app seem to have a mix of some framework, which i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

> What class can i check to how the querying string is decoded ?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

From class documentation:

- The plus sign `"+"` is converted into a space character `" "`